# Is there a REST Api for Active Admin?

Tags: activeadmin

Is there a way to access the data from Active Admin?
Im creating a mobile app that will connect to an active admin website.
I need to retrieve data from the website.

Answer (score 0):

We are using "active_model_serializers" gem for this. To make it work just:

1. Add active_model_serializers to your `Gemfile`
2. Add the following to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```rb
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
  before_action { self.namespace_for_serializer = ::Admin }
end
```

3. Put your serializers into `app/serializers/admin/` folder

```rb
# app/serializers/admin/user_serializer.rb
module Admin
  class UserSerializer < ::ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :username
  end
end
```

And that's it. Now you should be able to make requests with JSON format to your ActiveAdmin endpoints.